# Spring Boot integration test with @PostConstruct depends on @Before section

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I write integration test for SpringBoot application with opportunity to run multiple tests simultaneously they have file system dependencies that's why I need to create unique root folder for each integration test.

I have a spring bean in production app that have `@PostConstruct` section to perform long-running operations. These long-running operations rely on file system structure that I prepare in `@Before` section of unit-tests.

Unique folders for simultaneously running tests are set via `root.directory=target/results/#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}`. This property is injected as `@Value` in spring `@Component` class to avoid re-calculation root directory in different places.

The main issue is following: I need to prepare folders which name should be specified via `application.properties` with some resources(copy files, folders) in @Before test-section and run `@PostConstruct` only after all resource are prepared.

I tried several variants: 1) autowire in the test a bean with `@PostConstruct` and invoke it programmatically in the end of `@Before` - it's a single working case and it looks strange and fragile
2) Replace `@PostConstruct` with `InitializingBean` and `afterPropertiesSet` - it doesn't work. Because I have a value for folder name on bean initialization stage but without copied resources that I copy in `@Before` test section

I hope I explained well. I will be appreciate with any help or advice.

Comment: You mean, your `@PostConstruct` is being ran before the `@Before` is finished? From what I understood, all you need is to guarantee the prior execution inside the `@Before`.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault with adding comments `@PostConstruct` is invoked while spring context is initializing. `@Before` runs after it

Answer (score 1):

Your Question are bit vague but to answer the issues.

> The main issue is following: I need to prepare folders which name should be specified via application.properties with some resources(copy files, folders) in `@Before` test-section and run `@PostConstruct` only after all resource are prepared.

1. Make Sure you are running Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "myFileName=test.txt")
```

2. In test `@Before` use

```
@Rule 
public final TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
temporayFolder.newFile( use @Value here)
```

3. So `@Before` will run before any spring boot startup and then call your function in one of the unit test methods